# How to delete a single cookie in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cookies

How can i delete a single cookie and not all of my cookies using vb.net like probably get the cookie by it's name and delete it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
If (Not Request.Cookies("UserSettings") Is Nothing) Then
    Dim myCookie As HttpCookie
    myCookie = New HttpCookie("UserSettings")
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1D)
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie)
End If
```

Got directly from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: for some reason that is not working for me and i did use trhat before coming here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        Dim currentUserCookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("UserSettings")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("UserSettings")
    currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)
    currentUserCookie.Value = Nothing
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie)
```